# Actual data around a random date

Tags: mysql, date, max

I have a table with products and a table with product proporties

Products layout:

- ProductID
- Name
- Species
- Description

Product Proporties layout:

- ProductProportyID
- Amount
- Price
- PricePerPiece
- checkdate
- ProductID

Every night I run a query to actualize the prices and amounts. When there is a difference, there will be a new record added to Product Proporties with the actual prices and amounts. When there is no difference nothing happens.

It is possible that an update query updates just a part of the products and not all of them (because some of them are indeed more expensive or cheaper and some of them won't have a price or amount alteration.

I want to show the appropriate prices and amounts of a given date, which is completely random. I other words: I want all the prices and amounts of the products which were actual around the given date.

And that's where the problem rises, because my brain begins to leak out of my ears when I think of the right way.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT product.*, proporties.* 
FROM products product 
LEFT JOIN productproporties proporties 
ON product.ProductID = proporties.ProductID 
WHERE max(proporties.checkdate) <= '25-10-1979 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY proporties.checkdate DESC
```

But this doesn't seem to work:). Could anyone be so kind to kick me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what you mean by "I want to show the apropriate prices and amounts of a given date". Be as detailed as you can, with data examples if possible

Comment: Ofcourse I meant appropriate :) Anyway, I want all the prices and amounts which where actual on a given date. Is that better?

Comment: I assume based on checkdate. Which database are you using?